# I can not use bazel to build tensorflow because I installed bazel with bazelisk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tensorflow, bazel

I installed a bazelisk exe file and included that file in my environmental Path variable. I can now run bazelisk commands but no bazel commands and I think I was told that that was normal. Is it? If it is, if I cd into my tensorflow folder and run `python ./configure.py` because I think that that is a step I need to do to build tensorflow from source I get the message `Cannot find bazel. Please install bazel.` What am I supposed to do? I am using python 3.6.2 and windows 10 and bazelisk is on v1.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename bazelisk to bazel because it is just a wrapper for bazel